# using ffmpeg in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

I have to use ffmpeg in my project to convert an audio file from wav t mp3,pcm and vox. my project is javascript/php built can anyone direct me how to use ffmpeg.I've been reading a lot and now that it depends on the command lines.but where to  write these command lines.If someone can show me a demo of how to use it i will thankful
I have found this function, but don't know how to give it the file to convert.

```
 function getFFMPEGWorker() {
      // regexps for extracting time from ffmpeg logs
      var durationRegexp = /Duration: (.*?), /
      var timeRegexp = /time=(.*?) /;
      var duration;

      var ffmpegWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
      var durationLine;
      ffmpegWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
          var message = event.data;
          console.log(message.type);
          if (message.type === "ready" && window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
              // script loaded, hide loader
              $('#loading').hide();
          } else if (message.type == "stdout") {
              console.log(message.data);
          } else if (message.type == "stderr") {
              console.log(message.data);
              // try to extract duration
              if (durationRegexp.exec(message.data)) {
                  duration = timeToSeconds(durationRegexp.exec(message.data)[1]);
              }
              // try to extract time
              if (timeRegexp.exec(message.data)) {
                  var time = timeToSeconds(timeRegexp.exec(message.data)[1]);
                  if (duration) {
                      $("#progress").text("Progress: " + Math.floor(time / duration * 100) + "%");
                      $("#progress").show();
                  }
              }
          } else if (message.type == "done") {
              var code = message.data.code;

             console.log(message.data);
              var outFileNames = Object.keys(message.data.outputFiles);

              console.log(outFileNames);
              if (code == 0 && outFileNames.length) {
                  var outFileName = outFileNames[0];

                  var outFileBuffer = message.data.outputFiles[outFileName];

                  var src = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([outFileBuffer]));

                  $("#downloadLink").attr('href', src);
                  $("#download").show();
              } else {
                  $("#error").show();
              }
              $("#converting").hide();
              $("#progress").hide();
          }
      }, false);
      return ffmpegWorker;
  }

  // create ffmpeg worker
  var ffmpegWorker = getFFMPEGWorker();
  var ffmpegRunning = false;

  $('#convert').click(function() {
      // terminate existing worker
      if (ffmpegRunning) {
          ffmpegWorker.terminate();
          ffmpegWorker = getFFMPEGWorker();
      }
      ffmpegRunning = true;

      // display converting animation
      $("#converting").show();
      $("#error").hide();

      // hide download div
      $("#download").hide();

      // change download file name
      var fileNameExt = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

      var outFileName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.')) + "." + getOutFormat();

        $("#downloadLink").attr("download", outFileName);
      $("#downloadLink").text(outFileName);

      var arguments = [];
      arguments.push("-i");
      arguments.push(fileName);

      arguments.push("-b:a");
      arguments.push(getBitrate());

      switch (getOutFormat()) {
          case "mp3":
              arguments.push("-acodec");
              arguments.push("libmp3lame");
              arguments.push("out.mp3");
              break;

          case "wma":
              arguments.push("-acodec");
              arguments.push("wmav1");
              arguments.push("out.asf");
              break;

          case "pcm":
              arguments.push("-f");
              arguments.push("s16le");
              arguments.push("-acodec");
              arguments.push("pcm_s16le");
              arguments.push("out.pcm");
      }

      ffmpegWorker.postMessage({
          type: "command",
          arguments: arguments,
          files: [
              {
                  "name": fileName,
                  "buffer": fileBuffer
              }
          ]
      });
  });
```

Comment: You can't use JavaScript to control ffmpeg directly. You're going to have to make an ajax call to a server, which you use to run ffmpeg.

Comment: you mean that the ffmpeg line commands should be at the server side?

Comment: ok thanks that was helpful,but through my search I found the above function.is it helpful and how can I give it the file to convert?or it is preferable that I use the ajax?